# Switching between iterations of echo commands (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a bomb virus for fun that flashes a bunch of windows with one set of text on it then after a certain number of iterations flashes a bunch of windows with a separate set of text and back and forth. I am having trouble getting it to switch from one set of text to the other. It just stays on one set the whole time. Here is what I got so far.

```
start 123.bat

echo off
set /a count=1
set /a coun=1
:first
timeout /t 1
echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS

echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS
set /a count=%count%+1
if %count%==25 (goto next)
goto first

:next
timeout /t 1
echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED   

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED   

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED   

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED   

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED   

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED

echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET      YOUR EYES CHECKED 
set /a coun=%coun%+1
if %coun%==25 (goto first)
goto next
```

Any help on making this work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Basic debugging would be to add an additional echo statement that outputs the value of `count` to see exactly what's happening. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is malicious, _not fun_, in nature.

Comment: compo I thought it was fun. You should try it out. It is funnner when you leave the boxes open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `count` and `coun` variables should be initialized to `1` *every time* that the block of commands is executed, that is, you may insert an additional label, `:first0` for example, and put `set count=1` below it (with `:first` label below it), and fix the *corresponding* `goto first` command. The same for `:next` label and `coun` variable. BTW, in this way, it is no longer necessary to use different variables for the two loops...

However, it is simpler using `for /L` command this way:

```
@echo off

:first
for /L %%f in (1,1,25) do (
   timeout /t 1
   for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS
)

:next
for /L %%n in (1,1,25) do (
   timeout /t 1
   for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED
)

goto first
```

You may also create an *infinite loop* using a `for /L` command with no loop values:

```
@echo off

for /L %%x in () do (

for /L %%f in (1,1,25) do (
   timeout /t 1
   for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do echo FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS    FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS   FOLLOW THIS        FOLLOW THIS
)

for /L %%n in (1,1,25) do (
   timeout /t 1
   for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do echo THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET YOUR EYES CHECKED    THEN GET     YOUR EYES CHECKED
)

)
```